# CORONA SDK : playing sound randomly

Tags: audio, random, coronasdk

I'm in middle of creating a game and I wanted to play specific sounds when the player plays the game I keep losing  my audio when my game goes through the storyboard

```
-------------AUDIO STUFF-----
------------SOUND 1-------------
colsound = audio.loadSound("crowd.mp3")
function playSound( event)

    audio.play(colsound) 

end

    timer.performWithDelay(1000, playSound)
------------SOUND 2-------------
crowd = audio.loadSound("applause.wav")

function playSound1(event) 
    audio.play(crowd) 
end
timer.performWithDelay(2000, playSound1)

------------------------------------
```

I want to play sounds randomly (create a table then call the sounds to be played randomly without forgetting about the delay because it needs to be played during a specified time) .

Comment: can you explain clearly?

Answer (score 0):

Try the callback listener:

```
 local function narrationFinished( event )
    print( "Narration Finished on channel", event.channel )
    if ( event.completed ) then
        print( "Narration completed playback naturally" )
    else
        print( "Narration was stopped before completion" )
    end
end
local narrationChannel = audio.play( narrationSpeech, { duration=30000, onComplete=narrationFinished } )
```

Comment: and how I'm I gonna refer to my sounds ? I'm not familiar with the code that you wrote .